# Detecting Each of Curve in Opencv

Tags: opencv, detect

I have an image and image has lots of curves I want to detect each of curve and I want to save these curves coordinates  Firstly I used contour but I cant separet each of curve 
[image]

I want find detect each curves like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would proceed. Using a grid I would sample the image over small regions, collect data part of the white lines, and use a collinear function to test and group if points are part of lines, with additional tolerance, the line can Be a slightly curved lines.